# Language issues with SQL Server in-place upgrade

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, sql-server

I have an instance of SQL Server 2008 R2 which has been installed off localized (German) media. I need to run an in-place upgrade to SQL Server 2012, but get stuck in a chicken-and-egg problem:

- as the server's MUI is ENU, I cannot run the installer off German SQL Server media (*"The SQL Server license agreement cannot be located for the selected edition"*)
- as the old install's language is German, I cannot run the ENU SQL Server setup (cross-language upgrade is not supported)

How would I resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After poking the install with sharp sticks for a while, I have discovered that installing the [German MUI language pack for Windows Server 2008 R2](http://www.microsoft.com/de-de/download/details.aspx?id=1246) and switching the user's current language to German will allow the localized SQL Server 2012 installer to proceed (curiously it will still display US-English installer dialogs). My in-place upgrade is running now.

This is basically what [the reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144258%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) is telling to do:

> Localized versions of SQL Server are supported on English-language versions of supported operating systems through the use of Windows Multilingual User Interface Pack (MUI) settings.
>
> [...]
>
> If the settings do not match the language of the localized SQL Server to be installed, then use the following procedures to correctly set these operating system settings. [...]